# Calculate sum of order with a list and a separate class

Tags: c#, list, class, methods

So I'm trying to learn from an old test I failed.
I have to create a class called Article and then create a method called OrderSum that takes a list from the article class as input (List) which then returns the sum of an imaginary order. I'm completely blocked as to how to continue, what I've done so far is:

The Method:

```
public static decimal OrderSum(List<Article>order)
    {
        decimal orderTotal = 0m;
        bool run = true;
        for (int i = 0; run ==true; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to GIVE US YOUR MONEY INC");
            Console.WriteLine("Add an article?j/n");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            if(answer == "j")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please write the article Id:");
                string getArticleId = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Please write the name of article {getArticleId}:");
                string getArticleName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine($"Please write the quantity of {getArticleName} you would like to order:");
                int getArticleQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine($"Please write the price of {getArticleName}:");
                decimal getArticlePrice = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                orderTotal += (getArticleQuantity * getArticlePrice);
                order.Add(new Article() { Id = getArticleId, Name = getArticleName, Price = getArticlePrice, Quantity = getArticleQuantity });
                
            }
            else if(answer == "n")
            {
                run = false;
            }
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total price for your order is:{orderTotal}");
        return orderTotal;

    }
```

And the Class:

```
class Article
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Article:{0} {1} {2} {3}", Id, Name, Quantity, Price);
    }
}
```

But this is wrong, I don't know how to do it the "right" way.

This is what I'm supposed to feed to test if its right:

```
    List<Article> order = new List<Article>            
{                
new Article                
{                    
Id = "8ec144e4-0b9c-4689-95a1-95e9805cdc96",                     
Name = "Comfy Sofa",                     
Quantity = 1,                     
Price = 199.99m                
}                ,                
new Article                
{                    
Id = "b47a4226-36af-4d5a-904a-7ef7a8325ab8",                     
Name = "Lepoard Print Curtains",                     
Quantity = 2,                     
Price = 10                
}                ,                
new Article                
{                    
Id = "ada7292c-fb14-465e-b26e-e5575714a268",                    
Name = "Silky Smooth Carpet",                    
Quantity = 1,                    
Price =  59.99m                
}                ,                
new Article                
{                    
Id = "37da94a2-e59d-44a6-8a14-533554ed6038",                    
Name = "Super Soft Butt Pillow",                    
Quantity = 4,                    
Price = 8.99m                
}            
};
```

.

I'm grateful for any guidance! :)

Okay so I did it this way instead:

Class

```
class Article
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Article(string Id, string Name, int Quantity, decimal Price)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
        this.Price = Price;
    }

}
```

Main Method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Article> order = new List<Article>();
        order.Add(new Article("8ec144e4-0b9c-4689-95a1-95e9805cdc96", "Comfy Sofa", 1, 199.99m));
        order.Add(new Article("b47a4226-36af-4d5a-904a-7ef7a8325ab8", "Leopard Print Curtains", 2, 10));
        order.Add(new Article("ada7292c-fb14-465e-b26e-e5575714a26", "Silky Smooth Carpet", 1, 59.99m));
        order.Add(new Article("37da94a2-e59d-44a6-8a14-533554ed6038", "Super Soft Butt Pillow", 4, 8.99m));
        Console.WriteLine(OrderSum(order));


        /*List<Article> order = new List<Article> 
        { new Article { Id = "8ec144e4-0b9c-4689-95a1-95e9805cdc96", Name = "Comfy Sofa", Quantity = 1, Price = 199.99m }, 
          new Article { Id = "b47a4226-36af-4d5a-904a-7ef7a8325ab8", Name = "Lepoard Print Curtains", Quantity = 2, Price = 10 }, 
          new Article { Id = "ada7292c-fb14-465e-b26e-e5575714a268", Name = "Silky Smooth Carpet", Quantity = 1, Price = 59.99m }, 
          new Article { Id = "37da94a2-e59d-44a6-8a14-533554ed6038", Name = "Super Soft Butt Pillow", Quantity = 4, Price = 8.99m } };*/
    }
```

I tried writing the input data the way the teacher wanted us to copy paste (what's commented out)but I keep getting "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required format parameter 'Id' of ' Article.Article(string, string, int, decimal)'. Tried moving things around but I don't really know why I get the error.

OrderSum Method:

```
        public static decimal OrderSum(List<Article>order)
    {
        decimal orderSum=0m;
        foreach(var articleTotal in order)
        {
            orderSum +=articleTotal.Quantity *articleTotal.Price;
        }
        return orderSum;
    }
```

Comment: The given input is a code snippet, which you can just copy and paste to your `Main()` without those `Console.Read`. In the `OrderSum` you should loop through the given `List<Article> order` and calculate their sum (instead of the new ones you've just Read)

Comment: There appears to be a disconnect in what the `OrderSum` is “supposed” to do and what it is actually doing. From the requirement statement… _”create a method called OrderSum that takes a list from the article class as input (List) which then returns the sum of an imaginary order.”_ … ? The `OrderSum` code is NOT doing this. The code is taking the `List<Article> order`, then awkwardly creates a loop that asks the user to “add” items to the order list. Then keeps a “total” of ONLY the “added” items.

Comment: Why is the code “adding” items to the order list? This is not what the requirement is asking you to do. It simply says sum the `Article` objects in the given list `order.` It does not say “add” items to the list.

Comment: The portion of the code that asks the user to “add” items to the list should be a separate/different method. Something like a “GetOrderFromUser” method that returns a `List<Article>` from the items the user input. Then pass that list to the `OrderSum` method when the user is finished ordering items. Point being, you need to separate the “input” from the `OrderSum` method. All the `OrderSum` method should do is return the sum.

Comment: @SGKoishi Thanks for the input! I tried following it and updated it above, does that look better?

Comment: `OrderSum` does work as expected. You're getting the error about `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required format parameter of Article.Article` because you add a constructor. Here's a example: [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#gist:96b0d8a5d6b569eacc199fabd56cf755)